# How does representationalism respond to the "Mary's room argument"?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, physicalism, knowledge-representation

So here's Frank Jackson himself responding to his own argument using "representationalism":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPT0BE1WAHk

So as I'm understanding Frank's newer view... when Mary "sees" red she's not learning anything new... what's happens according to Frank is that the brain is urging along knowledge about the physical world through experience/sensation... so it's a new way of absorbing old information.

Puzzled by this response. I mean it seems to me Mary at least learns what it is like to have this new type of brain experience she didn't have before. Even if the seeing of red is a "representation"... Mary still attains knowledge of that representation which she didn't have before. Am I missing something?

Comment: "new way of absorbing old information" is very persuasive. But it doesn't explain "what it is like to" experience (i.e. see) something as red (as opposed, presumably, to grey). Whether that amounts to knowledge (in the sense that it can be fully expressed in true/false propositions) is the central issue. So I don't think you are missing anything and the proposed answer isn't a full response to the argument. But I don't have a better answer yet.

Comment: SEP calls a variant of this the [Acquaintance Hypothesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge/#NoPropKnow2AcquHypo) of Conee that postulates  "knowledge by acquaintance" as a third category in addition to propositional and ability knowledge. Whether one still calls it "knowledge" or not (as Jackson prefers) is a terminological issue, but AH allows physicalists to avoid the conclusion of the argument. Representationalist interpretations of the "phenomenal perspective" have been given by [Tye and Lycan](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia-knowledge/#VariNewKnowFactView).

Comment: Merely sitting and watching any representational content in a Cartesian theatre even for a long time perhaps would never gain any virtuous knowledge for Mary since to be able to see the empirical red qualia suddenly now must indicate some sufficient albeit potentially extremely hidden reason for her to enact and utilize said redness in some future for her, in the same manner as the ancient man escaped from the Cave to be able to see the Sun for the first time. Ergo her true acquired knowledge proof is still yet to be checked later...